# How to use semaphore in perl

Tags: perl

help me how and where i have to use semaphore to have control while printing into the output file "temp.out".

`open(OUT,">temp.out");`

`open(IN,"temp.txt");`

```
while(<IN>)
{
    $line = $_;
```

--> for each of this line i want to do some work using thread_main.

"thread_main --> branches to thread1, thread2, thread3;"
    thread1 does IO (read) operation on file1.txt - should sync with sem1
    thread 2 does IO (read) operation on file2.txt - should sync with sem2
    thread3 does IO (read) operation on file3.txt - should sysn with sem3

```
thread1 -> returns var1 
`var1 = thread1->join();` thread2 works on thread1 return data
thread2 -> returns var2
`var2 = thread1->join();` thread3 works on thread2 return data
thread3 -> returns var3
thread3->join();
```

these threads will end up with some variables which i want to print in to a file.
   `printf(OUT "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",$var1,$var2,$var3);` -> should sync with sem_main
}

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to use semaphores, but I don't think you actually do - a semaphore as a specific meaning in concurrent programming, which is basically a 'global flag' of some kind to handle resource 'ownership' and limits.

If this is what you need, then you can implement a basic version using `lock`, and a more fully featured version using `Thread::Semaphore`;

However, it looks to me like you don't, you're just trying to collate data from your threads.

For a single value - just start in a scalar context, and use `return`/`join`.

E.g.:

```
 sub worker_thread {
      #do stuff;
       return $value; 
 }


 my $thr = threads -> create ( \&worker_thread ); 

 #will block until 'thr' finishes. 
 my $result_from_thread = $thr -> join();
```

However, I'd generally advocate using `Thread::Queue` for passing values around threads, using `enqueue` and `dequeue` (and `end`).

```
my $result_q = Thread::Queue -> new();

sub worker_thread {
    my ( $filename ) = @_; 
    #run loop
        #do stuff
        $result_q -> enqueue ( $result );
    #exit loop
 }

 #create threads - use a loop if you need several, passing parameters is good too. 
foreach my $filename ( @file_list ) {
    my $thr = threads -> create ( \&worker_thread, $filename ); 
}

foreach my $thread ( threads -> list() ) {
   $thread -> join();
}

$result_q -> end();

while ( my $result = $result_q -> dequeue ) {
   #do something with $result;
}
```

You can use this approach if you've got a large number of files too - spawning lots of threads gets expensive quite quickly, but you can create a pool of 'worker' threads, and feed them a list of filenames in a queue.

I would however suggest you consider *why* you're threading here though. Usually threading is done to avoid blocking calls and get more CPU time. Reading files is a form of blocking IO, but doing in 3 in parallel won't necessarily get you better performance, if they're coming from the same storage subsystem. Your limiting factor won't be your CPU/memory, but rather how fast your disks spin - something you can't improve, and might well make worse by trying to thread.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting I have 1 multi-threading perl which work based on this logic. After I all the threads I execute 2 methods:

```
sub is_running(){
    my $threads_num=0;
    foreach (@threads){
        if ($_-is_joinable()){
            $threads_num++;
        }
    }
    if ( $threads_num == @machines ) {
        return 0; # All threads are completed
    }
    return 1; # Not all threads are completed
}
```

This one is checking if all threads have finished since depending on your implementation it's possible for the main thread to exit without waiting for the subthreads which have been started.

```
my $count=30;
while ((is_running)&&($count  0)){
    $count--;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Since I'm doing ssh commands with the threads I'm having a timeout if some of them have stuck somewhere.

After that timeout i call this method :

```
sub return_result(){
    my $machine_num=0;
    foreach (@threads){
        if ($_-is_joinable()){
            push(@results,$machines[$machine_num].$_-join());
            if ( $results[$machine_num] !~ OK){
                $rc=1;
            }
        }else{
            my $id=$_-tid();
            push(@results,$machines[$machine_num] TIMEOUT);
            $_-detach();
            $rc=1;
        }
        $machine_num++;
    }
    if ( $rc == 0 ) {
        $result=The execution of '$com' has returned '$res' on all hosts OK ;
    }else{
    $result=The execution of '$com' has NOT returned '$res' on some hosts ERROR ;
    }
    foreach(@results){
        $result.=$_;
    }
    return $result br;
}
```

Basicly it's checking if a thread is joinable ( have finished it's job ) to push it result into an Array.